# Is Shell Script Enough For Standalone Application on Linux

Tags: scripts, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell Scripting for Linux Server Administration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147812/shell-scripting-for-linux-server-administration)

Can someone please tell me if writting Shell scripts is enough for making a standalone application for Linux based PC's? I'm only proficient in PHP/MySQL on Windows.

Thanks for you time and patience